# Requirements for German work visa

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, resident-permit

I had an interview in Germany 3 months ago and visited on a Schengen visa. To apply for a Schengen visa, I just needed the interview invitation letter with basic other documents, such as the application form, my passport etc. Nothing was complicated in that. Now I got the job offer and received the detailed contract from the company.

I thought that applying for a work permit/visa would be as easy as before, but it looks a little bit confusing. First of all, what visa do I need to apply for? I couldn't find the application form for this type on any website. If I would need to apply for a residence permit, then where should I apply (German embassy in Oman?) and what form do I need to fill? Do I need a verification of my PhD degree? I am currently working in Oman with a Pakistani passport.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply for a German national visa, not a Schengen visa.
The German embassy in Oman has all information on their web site: https://maskat.diplo.de/om-en/service/05-VisaEinreise/-/1509632